# Python, run a shell script as soon as the previous iteration ends.

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, shell, python-multithreading

I am trying to write a simple program to call a shell script. I need the shell script to be executed continuously, however, not in a given time interval, since I can't know exactly how long it will take for the process created by the shell script to finish. Currently I have used threading to run the script every N seconds. What I need is, as soon as "test.sh" ends, run "test.sh" again.

This is my current code.

```
import subprocess
import threading

looptime = 7.0

def recognize():
    threading.Timer(looptime,recognize).start()
    filepath = "/home/user/Downloads/image.jpg"

    output = subprocess.check_output(['dir/test.sh',str(filepath)])
    print ("python print\n%s" % output)

recognize()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `threading.Timer`. `subprocess.check_output`will block main process until child process finished.

```
import subprocess

def recognize():
    filepath = "/home/user/Downloads/image.jpg"

    output = subprocess.check_output(['dir/test.sh',str(filepath)])
    print ("python print\n%s" % output)

while True:
    recognize()
```

Comment: So, by removing the timer, it will run test.sh as soon as test.sh is finished? Is it truly that simple?

Comment: @GeorgeT. Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

Example for a bash script which will execute in endless loop the `test.sh` script, e.g.:

while loop

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    echo "running script"
    ./test.sh
done
```

for loop

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( ; ; ))
do
    echo "running script"
    ./test.sh
done
```

Comment: How would I go about getting the output back to the python program using this method? It is needed further down in the program, not simply for a print.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subprocess.check_call(cmd_line)`

It blocks until the subprocess has completed.

Once `check_call()` returns, you can launch a new instance immediately.

Comment: I'd have to look into this, as I'm not aware of cmd_line. Using this I could set the interval to i.e. 1 second and as soon as the process ends it would run again at the next second?

Comment: Same principle as check_output, cmd_line what this function receives as input - a string array